# Insert R equation like `z<-x^2/y^2` into Markdown in a neat form

Tags: r, latex, markdown, rstudio, equation

I have an equation like «z=x^2/y^2» written in r like:
`z<-'x^2/y^2'` , `z<-function(x,y) x^2/y^2`  or `z<-quote( x^2/y^2)`.
I want translate it to a neat form (like LaTeX), such that I would be able to insert it in R Markdown. I want knit it in .doc or .odt format.
Non of solutions I found satisfied me.
So I tried this:

```
>latexTranslate("x^2/y^2")#  It doesn`t expand fractions.
>xtable(z)
Error in UseMethod("xtable") : 
  no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "character"
>z<-matrix(z)
>xtable(z)
```

I got:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \hline
 & x \\ 
  \hline
1 & x\verb|^|2/y\verb|^|2 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I tried to paste it in markdown with my_equation $that_previous_equation$ ,$$that_previous_equation$$
with no proper result.

```
>z<-'x^2/y^2'
>toLatex(z)

Error in UseMethod("toLatex") : 
  no applicable method for 'toLatex' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Then I tried the same after converting the equation to class «call»

```
Error in UseMethod("toLatex") : 
  no applicable method for 'toLatex' applied to an object of class "name"
```

I also tried to start the same with class(z)=expression.

Than

```
> Hmisc::latex(z,file="")
i got:
%latex.default(z, file = "")%
\begin{table}[!tbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\tabularnewline
\hline
x^2/y^2\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}\end{center}

\end{table}
```

I tried to paste it in Markdown with no result. Markdown gave me empty .doc if I inserted it, or $$ $$ if I inserted it like equation. Packages 'knitr' and 'markdown' were on.
Than I compared this LaTeX equation with that I got from online converter. It looked weary different: `$\frac{x^{2}}{y^{2}}$`. I was able to knit it.
How to generate from R something that Markdown understands?

Comment: So you want `x^2/y^2` translated to `\frac{x^2}{y^2}`? This is confusing me since `x^2/y^2` is perfectly valid LaTeX syntax. How should a translating function know which you want? Is there a reason why you can't write the LaTeX formulas yourself?

Comment: Roland. I want to do it automatically. I want to use that process in a template. That template will analyze some data and formulas and give me the result in a neat .doc form.

Comment: asciimath seems to understand this fraction, but I don't know of a converter to latex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution my self:

```
library(Ryacas)
z<-"x^2/y^2"
Sym(z)
TeXForm(z)
```

It gives `"$\frac{x ^{2}}{y ^{2}} $"`. It works.

Comment: Just a tiny mistake, but it took me some minutes to figure out: It's `TeXForm` (with captial "X").

Comment: Just another proof of the cumbersome embarassment that Latex is when dealing with math. [AsciiMath](http://asciimath.org/) is what Pandoc and RMarkdown should aim to support. What TeX does is typesetting, as opposed to math expression encoding, so people that know how to write math need to learn a (complex and cryptic) typesetting language for math. All mathematical structural info ends up being encrypted in a unsightly way that is bery hard to read unless rendered, let alone modified.